# Unable to select dropdown value using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I need to select a dropdown value , I checked the code it doesnt contain select class. Is there any way we can select the value without select class

By this I am clicking on dropdown which then enables the dropdown values
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='ot-lookup__input-container'])").click()`
That is the dropdown

The code for Xpath is : (**it is same for every value)

```html
<button _ngcontent-fru-c1=""
class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_entity slds-listbox__option_has-meta tabbable-button"
role="option" 
type="button"
id="listbox-option-unique-id-[object Object]">
<!----><!---->Skipped<!---->
</button>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi , Is there any possibility of the dropdown value takes from                              
 Country = ['Germany', 'Netherlands'], I am using google speech and storing the soken country in query
     for Country in query:
         if Country in Country:
            wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='ot-lookup__input-container'])").click()
            wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[normalize-space()=]+:{query}"))).click()

Answer (score 0):

You can. Click to open dropdown and then click on required option (in your case button). In code below I used `WebDriverWait` to wait until the button with text **Skipped** will be clickable:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# ...

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# ...

driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='ot-lookup__input-container'])").click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[normalize-space()='Skipped']"))).click()
```